# How to upgrade sencha app to the latest Sencha CMD?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I generated my Sencha App using Sencha CMD version 4.0.1.45. Then I downloaded Sencha CMD version 4.0.2.67. Now when inside my application folder I am running command to deploy it on Android, then it is showing the following error:

**The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (4.0.1.45)
the current is 4.0.2.67.
Please run "sencha app upgrade" to update to 4.0.2.67.**

I went to the application folder and then ran this command
**sencha app upgrade path/to/senchacmd.**
In my case senchacmd is installed in home/bin/Sench/CMD/4.0.2.67. But when I run this command, it shows the following error

**Command must be run from a framework folder**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when updating to Ext JS 5.1.0.47. I have white spaces in my path to, but even enquoting the path wouldn't help.

Well, turns out that

```
sencha app upgrade -ext
```

Upgrades the SDK from the online repo, so all's good.

Answer (score 0):

**sencha app upgrade path/to/senchacmd**

The path variable you are using in this command in wrong.

Try asking for help on this command using **sencha help app upgrade**, it clearly shows the usage is 
**sencha app upgrade /path/to/sdk**.

ie its the path to sdk (like touch-2.3.0), not the path to sencha CMD .

Hope it will be helpful....